# How can I prevent a cmd.exe window from showing when a .bat script is run via Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server

I have a `.bat` script scheduled to run every 5 minutes via Windows Task Scheduler on a Windows Server 2008.

### .bat script:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\scriptord.vbs //Nologo A > \\192.168.100.1\accounts\scriptord
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\scriptord.vbs //Nologo B > \\192.168.100.2\accounts\scriptord
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe C:\scriptord.vbs //Nologo C > \\192.168.100.3\accounts\scriptord
```

### Problem

The problem is that every 5 minutes I get a black and white `cmd.exe` window on screen that stays for around 2 minutes while the script runs.

How can I prevent this window from opening when Task Scheduler runs it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` as user, unless your script needs resources only your user has access to (like eg. remote shares)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is usually running the task under different user account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What user account should I use? I am using Administrator on the server and this is the only account that we use. Is there some system user that I can set it to and does that user then need to be logged on for it to run?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the batch script using VBS. The below code will hide the console

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("Batchfile.bat"), 0, True
```

so run this script through windows task scheduler instead of the batch and the console will no longer appear.